# Unable to use "gist_ltree_ops(siglen=100)" for setting signature strength in EF Core code first approach

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ltree

I am using EF Core code first approach and trying to configure signature strength of the column type ltree using the below snippet.

```
public class Node
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public LTree Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("ltree");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasIndex(x => x.Path).HasMethod("gist");           

}
```

This just creates an index with the default signature length of 8 bytes.
I want to override this signature length by explicitly specifying the length like as we do in the postgres query editor

```
CREATE INDEX "IX_Nodes_Path" ON public."Nodes" USING gist ("Path" gist_ltree_ops (siglen='100'))
```

Any pointers to achieve this will be of immense help.

I am using posgres version 14.0, EF Core 6 rc, npgsql 6 rc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't supported by the Fluent API - you'll have to edit your scaffolded migration and use [raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#adding-raw-sql) to express this.

The provider does have a Fluent API for specify the operator class, but not for specifying options (e.g. siglen).

Comment: @Rojy . Thanks for the response..
I tried setting the operator using Fluent API.. but failed to do so.
As I keep getting an error saying that.. its not recognized..

Comment: You'll need to post the code and the error.